# angular factory not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('pipelineChromeApp', [
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'LocalStorageModule'
])


angular.module('pipelineChromeApp')
.factory('Profile', [
'$http',
'apiUrl',
'localStorageService',
function ($http, apiUrl, localStorageService) {
  var baseUrl = apiUrl + 'profile.json?api_key=';

  return {
    login: function(apiKey) {
      return $http.get(baseUrl + apiKey);
    },

    logout: function() {
      localStorageService.clearAll();
      localStorageService.set('loggedIn', false);
      console.log("cleared local storage");
      return true;
    }
  }
}]);


angular.module('pipelineChromeApp')
.controller('LoginController', [
'$scope',
'Profile',
'$location',
function ($scope, Profile, $location) {
  $scope.apiKey = "";

  $scope.login = function(){
    debugger

    // Profile.login().then({
    //   $location.path( "/actions" );
    // });
  };
}]);
```

For some reason `Profile` isn't available in `LoginController`. Have I loaded things wrong?

Comment: What happens if you make the factory's module name `'profile'` and you include that in `LoginController` dependencies?

Comment: `angular.module('profile').factory('Profile',`...   `controller('LoginController', ['$scope','profile',..`

Comment: apiUrl?where does it come from

Comment: Actually, looks like there's not a problem. I was expecting to be able to go in the console and type "Profile" and see that object. It says it was undefined. But if I interact with it in the code it works ok. Odd..

Comment: Maybe it's b/c it hadn't been new'd up yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, the problem you have is in the console, and I assume the browser you're using is chrome. In chrome/v8, the javascript engine tries very hard to optimize your code, it will remove any unused function parameters. In your case, `Profile` isn't used anywhere in your function, so v8 has removed it.

That's also the reason why it works fine when you have some code to do with the `Profile`.

Usually I will add a `console.log()` to an empty function if I want to check some variables in the chrome console, like this:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    debugger;
    console.log(Profile);
};
```

Comment: All assumptions were correct. Thanks for the insight. That makes sense.